# How can I solve a string version of a calculation for a simple calculator?

Tags: java, calculator

This is a simple calculator where the user can type out the calculation and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>, and the calculator would determine if it is a valid calculation or not. If it is a valid calculation, the calculation is carried out. If not, an error message is written to the screen.

The  `calculation is carried out` part isn't finished.

Can someone suggest a solutions to the `getAnswer()` method.

It would be very much appreciated.

```
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Calculator extends JFrame{

    private interface CalculatorInterface {
        public void writeToScreen(String text);
        public void clearScreen();
        public String getScreenText();  
    }

    private class CalculatorPanel extends JPanel implements CalculatorInterface {

        private class NumberPanel extends JPanel implements CalculatorInterface {

            private static final int NUMTOTAL = 10;

            private CalculatorPanel calcPanel;
            private JButton[] numButtons;

            public NumberPanel(CalculatorPanel calcPanel) {
                this.calcPanel = calcPanel;
                buildLayout();
                addButtons();
            }
            private void buildLayout() {
                this.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

                GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(4,3);
                layout.setHgap(1);
                layout.setVgap(1);

                this.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3));

            }
            private void addButtons() {
                numButtons = new JButton[NUMTOTAL];

                for(int i = numButtons.length -1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
                    numButtons[i] = new JButton("" + i);
                    numButtons[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60,40));
                    numButtons[i].setFont(new Font("Sans serif", Font.PLAIN, 18));
                    numButtons[i].addActionListener(
                            new ActionListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                    String text = ((JButton)e.getSource()).getText().trim();
                                    if(getScreenText().equals("Invalid Calc")) {
                                        clearScreen();
                                        writeToScreen(text);
                                    }else {
                                        writeToScreen(text);
                                    }       
                                }
                            });
                    this.add(numButtons[i]);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void writeToScreen(String text) {
                calcPanel.writeToScreen(text);
            }
            @Override
            public void clearScreen() {
                calcPanel.clearScreen();

            }
            @Override
            public String getScreenText() {
                return calcPanel.getScreenText();
            }

        }

        private class OperPanel extends JPanel implements CalculatorInterface {

            private static final int ADD = 0;
            private static final int SUB = 1;
            private static final int MULT = 2;
            private static final int DIV = 3;
            private static final int OPENB = 4;
            private static final int CLOSEB = 5;
            private static final int CLEAR = 6;
            private static final int EQL = 7;


            private static final int OPERTOTAL = 8;

            private CalculatorPanel calcPanel;
            private JButton[] operButtons;

            public OperPanel(CalculatorPanel calcPanel) {
                this.calcPanel = calcPanel;
                buildLayout();
                addButtons();
            }

            private void buildLayout() {
                GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(4,1);
                layout.setHgap(1);
                layout.setVgap(1);

                this.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));
            }

            private void addButtons() {
                operButtons = new JButton[OPERTOTAL];

                operButtons[ADD] = makeButton(ADD, "+");
                operButtons[SUB] = makeButton(SUB, "-");
                operButtons[MULT] = makeButton(MULT, "*");
                operButtons[DIV] = makeButton(DIV, "/");
                operButtons[CLEAR] = makeButton(CLEAR, "CL");
                operButtons[EQL] = makeButton(EQL, "=");
                operButtons[OPENB] = makeButton(OPENB, "(");
                operButtons[CLOSEB] = makeButton(CLOSEB, ")");

                for(JButton button: operButtons) {
                    this.add(button);
                }   
            }

            private JButton makeButton(int index, String label) {   

                operButtons[index] = new JButton(label);
                operButtons[index].addActionListener(
                        new ActionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                String text = ((JButton)e.getSource()).getText();
                                if(text.equals("=")) {
                                    String screenText = getScreenText();
                                    clearScreen();
                                    try {
                                        writeToScreen(getAnswer(screenText));
                                    }catch(Exception excep) {
                                        writeToScreen("Invalid Calc");
                                    }
                                }else if(text.equals("CL")) {
                                    clearScreen();  
                                }else {
                                    writeToScreen(text);
                                }
                            }       
                        });

                return operButtons[index];      
            }


            private String getAnswer(String text) throws Exception {
                /*I'm trying to solve for any input by the user e.g
                 *(the stuff in square brackets represents what is displayed
                 * on the screen:.
                 *[1+1] (hits equals) [2]
                 *[1+2-3] (hits equals) [0]
                 *[1+2*3] (hits equals) [7]
                 *[10*(14+1/2)] (hits equals) [145]
                 */
                throw new Exception();
            }
            @Override
            public String getScreenText() {
                return calcPanel.getScreenText();
            }

            @Override
            public void clearScreen() {
                calcPanel.clearScreen();

            }

            @Override
            public void writeToScreen(String text) {
                calcPanel.writeToScreen(text);

            }

        }


        private NumberPanel numPanel;

        private OperPanel operPanel;
        private JTextField calcScreen;

        public CalculatorPanel(JTextField calcScreen) {
            this.calcScreen = calcScreen;

            buildNumPanel();
            buildOperPanel();

            buildCalcPanel();


        }
        private void buildNumPanel() {
            this.numPanel = new NumberPanel(this);
        }

        private void buildOperPanel() {
            this.operPanel = new OperPanel(this);
        }

        private void buildCalcPanel() {
            this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
            this.add(numPanel);
            this.add(operPanel);
        }


        @Override
        public void writeToScreen(String text) {
            calcScreen.setText(getScreenText() + text);     
        }

        @Override
        public String getScreenText() {
            return calcScreen.getText();
        }

        @Override
        public void clearScreen() {
            calcScreen.setText("");
        }
    }

    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JTextField calcScreen;

    private CalculatorPanel calcPanel;
    public Calculator() {
        buildScreen();

        buildCalcPanel();

        buildMainPanel();

        buildCalculator();
    }

    private void buildScreen() {
        this.calcScreen = new JTextField();
        this.calcScreen.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,50));
        this.calcScreen.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        this.calcScreen.setFont(new Font("Sans serif", Font.PLAIN, 30));

    }

    private void buildCalcPanel() {
        this.calcPanel = new CalculatorPanel(this.calcScreen);
    }

    private void buildMainPanel() {
        this.mainPanel = new JPanel();
        this.mainPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));
        this.mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this.mainPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        this.mainPanel.add(calcScreen);
        this.mainPanel.add(calcPanel);
    }

    private void buildCalculator() {

        this.add(mainPanel);
        this.setTitle("Calculator");
        this.pack();        
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Calculator calc = new Calculator();
    }

}
```

How can I check to see if a string is a valid calculation for a simple calculator?

Edit 1: Fixed a silly bug in the makeButton() method were I passed in the text of the button to be verified instead of the text on screen. (I'm an idiot.)

Edit 2: Removed the isValid(String text) from the code and make it so the getAnswer() method just threw an exception if input is not a valid calculation.

Comment: Validation is going to be tricky, but I suggest you start out solving the easiest cases first: `1+1`, `5+4+21`, `5*1.2`.  Then move to more complex equations, refactoring your code as you go.  My early solutions involved looking first for the operators, then their operands (the numbers). As I my understanding grew, I eventually developed calculators that turned string inputs into syntax trees, which I used for validation and calculation; but syntax trees are likely overkill for this problem.

Comment: For basic arithmetic operators, you can do this using a stack (and, if it's valid, calculate the result at the same time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As well mentioned in a previous `StackOverflow` answer ([Evaluating a math expression given in string form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form)), you could use `Javascript's` `ScriptEngine` to calculate expressions based on strings that you would retrieve from the Text Field. Place it in a `try-catch block` first to see if there's an error in the expression. In the catch block, set the variable storing whether its a valid expression or not to false.

```
boolean validExpression = true;

ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
String input = textField.getText() // Modify this to whatever variable you have assigned to your text field

try {
    System.out.println(engine.eval(foo));
} 
catch (ScriptException e) {
    validExpression = false;
    System.out.println("Invalid Expression");
}
```

Make sure you include the following imports:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
```

Although you could try to implement Shunting-Yard Algorithm or another arithmetic parser, this is simply a way more pragmatic solution.

Comment: Although this is nice to know, it's a) overkill for the use-case and b) does nothing to help someone learn how to parse expressions.